# What kind of professional(s) build/design factories?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, industrial-engineering

I have a small self-built food processing unit (500sqft) but it is very labor-intensive. I want to make a larger unit (45,000sqft) with 100x more output using factory machinery (automation, conveyor belts, etc).

My current unit is composed of a lot of electrical components and plumbing systems; it's not top notch and beyond my expertise to scale into something larger. It is a food manufacturing and processing plant with many chemical inputs.

I am not exactly sure who to contact regarding this build or where to begin my search.

Comment: Typically, you buy the building somewhere. Consult with your engineers about their requirements, and choose the building by balancing your money and what do they want. From that point, the building is given, and the engineers will tune it, what do they want and to where.

Comment: The types of engineers that would be applicable would be food processing engineers and possibly mechanical engineers. If neither of these people have enough skill to deal with the electrical side of things then an electrical engineer will be required. Generally, a food processing engineer or mechanical engineer who has experience in designing & constructing food processing equipment might know an electrical engineer to assist them with the design of the electrical systems.

Comment: How would I go about searching for these engineers? Because every time I search these terms online, the only results I get are related to jobs or engineering companies who worked on construction of commerical buildings and civil infrastructure.